# Accessing json attributes from marker - gmaps4rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, gmaps4rails, gmaps4rails2

I'm upgrading to gmaps4rails v2. I can't seem to access the marker json attributes from javascript. This worked in the previous version I was using (1.5.6)

Specifically

Buidling in controller:
@users = User.all

```
@hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@users) do |user, marker|
  marker.lat user.latitude
  marker.lng user.longitude
  marker.json({link: "someurl", current: true})
end
```

And in javascript:

```
handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
  markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
  console.log(markers[0].link);
  console.log(markers[1].current);
  handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
  handler.fitMapToBounds();
});

>undefined
>undefined
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed the new behaviour: it doesn't change objects, choice is yours.

You could do:

```
markers_json = <%=raw @hash.to_json %>;
markers = _.map(markers_json, function(marker_json){
  marker = handler.addMarker(marker_json);
  _.extend(marker, marker_json);
  return marker;
});
```

Comment: you're welcome! I know it could be painful for 1.x users so I try to keep an eye on stackoverflow :)