# Pass marker id to rails partial gmaps4rails v2

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I'm using `gmaps4rails` `v2` and passed the marker.id as my "Land.id." I'm trying to pass the variable into a partial the same way I passed it into the info window.

**Info Window: (lands_controller.rb)**

> @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@lands) do |land, marker|
>
> ```
> marker.lat land.latitude
>   marker.lng land.longitude
>   marker.title "#{land.name}"
>   marker.picture({
>    "url" => ActionController::Base.helpers.image_path("crosshair.png"),
>    "width" =>  10,
>    "height" => 10})
>   marker.infowindow render_to_string(partial: "/layouts/popupbox", locals: {l: land})
>   marker.json({ :id => land.id })
> end
> ```

Want to move the partial and load it when I click a marker:

**Map Partial (_gmap.html.erb)**

> google.maps.event.addListener(marker.getServiceObject(), 'click', function() {
>
> ```
>         land = <% Land.find_by_id(marker.id) %>;
>         $(#sidebar).html("<%= escape_javascript(partial: '/layouts/popupbox', locals: {l: land})%>");
>     });
> ```

This doesn't work, but is there a way to do this? it might be the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23121060/gmaps4rails-repeating-partials-for-markers) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766343/accessing-json-attributes-from-marker-gmaps4rails) but I couldn't fix it from those answers.

Comment: you cant mix ruby and js this way, this outputs static js

Comment: do you have an idea to work around this problem? thanks for the reply.

Comment: Provide the generated javascript, so I have a real idea

Comment: I think I can figure that part out. I actually have another problem. When I do `marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);` or `marker.infowindow()` in the click handler, it gives me an undefined error. This is actually related to my other question (which is solved), so I wasn't sure whether to comment there or here or just change this question.

Comment: as everywhere else, use `marker.getServiceObject().setAnimation`

Comment: that worked. I have another problem with setting the kml options. `var state_outlines = handler.addKml({
        url: "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/57600518/gzstate20m.kml",
        preserveViewport: true,
        suppressInfoWindows: true
    });` doesn't work, the view still resets and infowindows show up on the states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@apneadiving was correct, there is no way to render the partial from the js. If anyone else had a similar problem, I solved it by using a click handler with an ajax post request and loaded the partial from rails using jQuery.

**Map Partial (_gmap.html.erb)**

```
var n = marker.getServiceObject().title;
google.maps.event.addListener(marker.getServiceObject(), 'click', function() {
            $.post('/lands/sideinfo', { name: n });         
        });
```

**Router (routes.rb)**

```
resources :lands do
  collection {post :sideinfo}
end
```

**Controller (lands_controller.rb)**

```
def sideinfo
  @l=Land.find_by_name(params['name'])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

**View (sideinfo.js.erb)**

```
$("#info").html("<%= j render partial: '/layouts/popupbox', locals: {l: @l} %>")
```

Comment: In the click listner n is always give me last id.can you tell me how can i get particular marker id? Many Thanx in advance :)